# How to change key listener to mouse listener

Tags: java

I am developing a game (also not very experienced with java) and currently i have it set to use arrow keys to change the user's directions. I want to be able to use mouse/touchpad to change the user's direction or to make the user object follow the cursor (like the game agar.io) if possible. what do i need to do in order to get this to work. If i am missing something then i can add it but this should be enough code i think.

```
    keyDown[0] = false;
    keyDown[1] = false;
    keyDown[2] = false;
    keyDown[3] = false;
}


public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

        if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Player){
            //key events for player 1

            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W) {tempObject.setVelY(-5); keyDown[0] = true;}
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S) {tempObject.setVelY(+5); keyDown[1] = true;}
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {tempObject.setVelX(+5); keyDown[2] = true;}
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A) {tempObject.setVelX(-5); keyDown[3] = true;}

            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {tempObject.setVelY(-5); keyDown[0] = true;}
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {tempObject.setVelY(+5); keyDown[1] = true;}
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {tempObject.setVelX(+5); keyDown[2] = true;}
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {tempObject.setVelX(-5); keyDown[3] = true;}

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) System.exit(1);
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_P) Game.gameState = STATE.Pause;
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_O) Game.gameState = STATE.Game;
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

        if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Player){
            //key events for player 1

            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W) keyDown[0] = false;
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S) keyDown[1] = false;
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D) keyDown[2] = false;
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A) keyDown[3] = false;

            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) keyDown[0] = false;
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) keyDown[1] = false;
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) keyDown[2] = false;
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) keyDown[3] = false;

            //Vertical movement
            if(!keyDown[0] && !keyDown[1]) tempObject.setVelY(0);
            //Horizontal movement
            if(!keyDown[2] && !keyDown[3]) tempObject.setVelX(0);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How do you want the mouse to control movement? Should moving it move the player? Or does LMB move left and RMB right? Or perhaps there are buttons on the screen to click on?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I want the user object to follow the cursor like in the game agar.io if that makes any sense and currently you just hold the arrow keys and the object moves in the direction being clicked

Comment: You want to move the state management somewhere else.  You use what ever input you want to change the state, which the "main loop" will check and take appropriate action on. The basic idea is maintain some kind of `List` or `Set` which describes which "inputs" are currently active or not, a concept which is demonstrated in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41785697/graphics-stuttering-in-java-space-invaders/41787291#41787291). It then doesn't matter what the input is, only that the state is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in order to change the functionality to a mouse listener you woud just need to change a few things.

Currently you utilize the KeyListener class which listens to the keyboard

you probably have something that look like:

```
implements KeyListener
```

You would change that to:

```
implements MouseMotionListener
```

You can then change your key events to mouse events.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
```

is what is controling your velocity right now. Mouse movement events and listner methods can be found here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html

paying particular attention to:

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
```

The velocity computation psudo code would probably look something like:

```
centerX = window.width / 2;
centerY = window.height / 2;



deltaX = e.getX() - centerX;
deltaY = e.getY() - centerY;

scale = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(deltaX, 2) + Math.pow(deltaY, 2)) / speed;

tempObject.setVelY(deltaY / scale);
tempObject.setVelX(deltaX / scale);
```